# How can I remount external drives after a power failure?

Tags: filesystems, mount, raspberry-pi

I know I can run a script that basically does this: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/my_flashdrive/`. Is there a better way to do this on a small server with many external drives?

Comment: Is there any `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Im fairly new to linux, Is that a command you want me to run?

Comment: No it is the file that stores partitions, options and mount points under Linux.  Search on internet about it and its brother `mtab`. Btw with `file /etc/fstab` you can see which kind of file it is. With `cat nomefile` you will have it printed in the current shell... search for the *Intermediate bourn shell programming* pdf... about 20 pages to start to familiarise with Linux. [edit] your post adding specific doubt. Welcome aboard :)